# Close dialog misbehavior

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, vote-to-close

For replicating the behavior:

1. Open the close dialog by clicking on close
2. Then choose option off-topic
3. Then if you choose options like SSCCE problem, or minimal understanding, the *vote to close* button becomes active which is fine
4. But choose *Other* (where you have to type custom message) option, now the vote to close will be disabled
5. Go back to any other option like SSCCE problem, the ***vote to close button does not get enabled again***.

When going in *Other* option in off-topic dialog and then reverting back to any other option the *vote to close* button is not enabled.

**EDIT:**

For me it always stays disabled **for the first option I choose after *Other***, but after some other option is chose as @R.J. has suggested then the button gets enabled.

[image]

Comment: Its working partially fine for me. I'm unable to reproduce it fully. When you chose any other option after choosing *Other option*, it stays disabled for the first time, but if you choose some other option once more, *bam!*, its enabled again. Give this a try! :)

Comment: I can *sometimes* (3 out of 5 times) reproduce this with the steps you described. Firefox 25

Comment: When choosing Other there is a timer that start ticking. After about half a second, the "Vote To Close" button becomes disabled. If in that half second you chose something else... the button will still be disabled. Added this to the post to make the repro steps more reliable.

Comment: @R.J Yes true. I have edited the post to add that.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No the step 5 is not required to be done quickly. It stays that way.

Comment: OK, no repro here then. What browser/OS you have? Might be local issue with custom plugin/extension/add-on you have.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Why am I getting downvoted?? :(

Comment: You're not being downvoted, you just lost an upvote.

Comment: @Stijn yep my vote retracted as I can't repro using those steps.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Chrome v31.

Comment: I can reproduce it when waiting 2 seconds between changing the selected option (but like I mentioned, not always).

Comment: I can reproduce consistently without any timing shenanigans, using Firefox 25.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed in next build - `2013.11.29.1695` on meta and `2013.11.29.1182` on sites.

Comment: at which place we see this build numbers??

Comment: at the bottom of each page

Comment: thnk you m0sa .. i had this question from a while but it was so minor question that i dont want to open a new question for this .. now i got it...